# How to send a custom USB control transfer in Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, uart, cdc

I have a [XR21V1410](https://www.maxlinear.com/product/interface/uarts/usb-uarts/xr21v1410) USB-UART IC. It has a normal mode for 5...8 bits UART symbols and the wide mode for 9 bits UART symbols. As I understand, to enable the wide mode I shall change the UART custom register via USB. And to change this register I shall send the XR_SET_REG USB control command. The usbser.sys driver can send (as I understand) only SET_LINE_CODING, GET_LINE_CODING, SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE commands and so on.

How can I send the XR_SET_REG USB control command with WinAPI?